# Как подсчитать количество символов в каждой ячейке массива?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив:

```
const arr = ["user_name", "qwerty", "wasd"];
```

Мне нужно найти самый длинный элемент массива, но я не понимаю, как можно подсчитать количество символов в каждом элементе.

Comment: `arr[some_index].length`. [String.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length).

Comment: Заголовок вопроса не совпадает с телом вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если способ в лоб (и в зависимости куда этот результат должен быть выведен/положен). Один из вариантов:

1. Делаете цикл по каждому элементу массива (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration или https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
2. Объявляете переменную `itemCharsCount`, в которую будет заноситься количество символов элемента
3. Применяете **[String.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)** к элементу, чтобы узнать длину строки. Кладётеэто значение в `itemCharsCount`
4. Выводите это например через `console.log(itemCharsCount);`

%)

---

Отвечал на заголовок вопроса

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr = ["user_name", "qwerty", "wasd"];
console.log(arr.reduce((c,p) => c.length > p.length ? c : p));
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю насколько хороший вариант, но выполняет задачу.

```js
function longest(arr) {
  return arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    return b.length - a.length;
  })[0];
}

const arr = ["user_name", "qwerty", "wasd"]
let long = longest(arr);
console.info(long, long.length);
```